# Why does referencing undeclared variables throw a reference exception but referencing undeclared properties doesn't?

Tags: javascript, undefined, referenceerror

[Mozilla says that variables are properties of the global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object). If an object has a property that isn't defined, then trying to access it does not create a reference exception - it simply returns that the property is not defined.

If there is such a global object - then why does accessing its properties (ie: variables) that do not exist create reference errors? What is precisely the difference between these two scenarios?

Example:

```
console.log(x) //x is not declared -> reference error


var x = new Object();
console.log(x.property); //console.log: undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** The **way** the variable is accessed makes all the difference, not how it is stored.

---

First some background:

There are basically two ways how variables are "stored".

In a [*declarative* environment](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-declarative-environment-records), variables are stored in an internal data structure that is not accessible from user code.

In an [*object* environment](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object-environment-records), variables are stored as properties of a user code accessible object. The global environment happens to be an object environment (it's a bit more complicated than that but lets keep it simple). Therefore global variables are properties of the global object.

---

So why does accessing a non-existing global variable throw an error? Because it is **not** relevant how the variables are **stored**, only how the are **accessed**.

`foo` and `window.foo` are simply two different ways of accessing a global variable.

The language rules for evaluating a variable (`foo`) explicitly say that if the variable doesn't exist, throw a reference error (again, no matter how it is stored).*

[The language rules](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ordinaryget) for evaluating property access (`window.foo`) say that if the property doesn't exist, `undefined` should be returned.

And if you think about, this makes much more sense from a consistency perspective. Accessing `foo` should have the same result, no matter whether the variable is stored in a declarative environment or an object environment.

---

*: To be more precise:  It's the [`GetValue`](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-getvalue) function that causes the error to be thrown. `GetValue` is called almost everywhere when resolving a variable (exceptions are `typeof` and the grouping operator `(...)`).

Comment: So, short version: The "why" is "because JavaScript's standard says so", and the "why" for that is probably "because nobody did a great deal of planning for JavaScript so consistency was a pipe dream, and it's all held together with spit, bailing wire, and desperate attempts to maintain backwards compatibility".

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't see what's so inconsistent about this. Accessing a key of a dictionary that might exist or not is not an error, and simply gets `undefined` when it doesn't exist. In contrast, accessing a variable that is not declared anywhere is definitely a (programmer) mistake and justifies an exception.

Comment: @Bergi: We're not talking about dictionaries, we're talking about objects; even if JS folks frequently use them as string keyed dictionaries, it doesn't mean that's their primary purpose. It's weird to have reads of arbitrary attributes just blithely pretend they exist (requiring explicit test for missing in a language that theoretically offers exceptions, with the alternative being waiting for it to fail some arbitrary point in time long after the "real" error occurred). In most other languages, duck typing accesses like this raise an error immediately if the attribute doesn't exist.

Comment: @ShadowRanger JS objects were designed for *all* purposes :-) Surely it would make sense to throw exceptions when accessing the fields of records, so these conflicting choices are not optimal, but apparently the simplicity of having only a single object type was valued more.